# Memory leaks in Node.js cluster's master process

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

**Problem solved, just remove `silent` property from `cluster.setupMaster`, then it will not have memory leaks problem, could anyone tell me why it comes like this?**

I am working on a project done by `Node.js`, and when I added `cluster` to take advantages of multi-CPUs, things go strange.

I `fork()` worker process from master process, and the thing is my worker process works just fine and do not have a memory leak problem, but master process has it.

The code of master process which using `cluster` is :

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPU = require('os').cpus().length;

cluster.setupMaster({
        exec : '../worker/worker.js',
        silent : true
});

if(cluster.isMaster){
    for(var i=0; i< numCPU;i++){
        cluster.fork();
    }
}
```